# Calculating probability of stopping time by stochastic process

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stopping-times

A stopping time is given as $\tau = \text{inf}\lbrace t≥0 : X_t ≤ 0 \rbrace  $ and the stochastic process is defined as 
\begin{equation}   X_t = (a-B_t)e^{B_t} \end{equation}
where $a>0$ and $B_t$ is a standard continuous Brownian motion ( w.r.t. its augmented natural filtration $\mathcal{G_t}= \sigma(B_s | s≤t)$ $\vee$ $\mathcal{N} $ ) 
In the exercise, I am asked to compute: 
(1) $\mathbb{P} (\tau ≤ t)$ in terms of $a, t$ and $\Phi$ (the cdf of a standard normal).
(2) $\mathbb{P(\tau = + \infty)}$.

How would you tackle these types of problem? Can you help me solve this exercise?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: $e^{B_t} > 0$ for all $t$, so you're really looking for $\tau = \inf\{t \ge 0 : a - B_t \le 0\}$.  You can find the distribution of that $\tau$ using the reflection principle.

Comment: @user6247850 I have managed to solve the first question using your hint, what about the second one with $ \mathbb{P} (\tau = + \infty) $?

Comment: The second one should be easier: you can use that $\mathbb P(\tau = \infty) \le \mathbb P(\tau > T)$ for all $T$ and send $T \rightarrow \infty$.